How to optimized scss code to apply on specific selector?
I don't want to write a second-time label selector. How can I merge both CSS?
Don't apply padding-right for the .mat-checkbox selector.
label, .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label {
    color: #5b5b5b !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
}

label {
    padding-right: 1em;
}

I have tried but not working. Anyone can provide solution?
label, .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label {
    color: #5b5b5b !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    
    & {
        padding-right: 1em;
    }
}


&:not(:is(.mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label)) should probably work (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) - but if you have to repeat the full .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label part a second time, you're not winning too much either, I suppose.

This is not possible.
Your first rule applies to "all" elements, and its child rules can not apply to a single parent element.
You implemented it the best way possible IMO.
This document could be a good starting Point for learning scss:
https://gist.github.com/fredsiika/2958726da1f94a9bd447f4f7bd03a852

Okay, thanks!. Can you provide a document? So I can solve this type of query.

Sure. Take a look at my updated answer.

If .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label is also a <label>, you could try something like this.
label {
    color: #5b5b5b !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;

    &:not(.mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label) {
        padding-right: 1em;
    }
}



No, it isn't a label

Then it's impossible (or at least not with a reasonably simple syntax). Maybe just stick with what you have right now which is already quite clean.

Perhaps you can do this:
label {
   .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label {
      color: #5b5b5b !important;
      font-weight: 600 !important;
   }
   & {
      padding-right: 1em;
   }
}

Generated CSS:
label .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label {
  color: #5b5b5b !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}
label {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

